# NoneType error when attempting to parse JSON to csv

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary, nonetype

Thanks all - I cannot get around a 'NoneType' error when attempting to parse this code block.  The error pertains to the field 'Manufacturer'.  I've also attempted to format that line similarly to that of the 'name' element, in which case I'm haunted by a KeyError.  Thanks!

```
i=1

while i<101:
    print i

    bb_url = urllib2.Request("http://api.remix.bestbuy.com/v1/products(sku=*)?show=sku,name,description,image,manufacturer,upc,department,class,subclass&format=json&sort=sku.asc&page=" + str(i) + "&pageSize=100&apiKey=**************")
    bb_json = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(bb_url))

    print bb_json

    for product in bb_json['products']:
        row = []

        row.append(product['sku'])
        if product['name']:
            row.append(str((product['name']).encode('utf-8')))
        else:
            row.append("")
        row.append(str(product.get('description',"")))
        row.append(str(product['image'])+ " ")
        row.append(str(product.get('manufacturer',"").encode('utf-8')))
        row.append(str(product.get('upc','').encode('utf-8')))
        row.append(str((product['department']).encode('utf-8')))
        row.append(str((product['class']).encode('utf-8')))
        row.append(str((product['subclass']).encode('utf-8')))

        csv_writer.writerow(row)    

    i = i+1
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Py\Pointinside\q1\bb_ext.py", line 39, in <module>
    row.append(str(product.get('manufacturer',"").encode('utf-8')))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: is it possible that some products may not have a manufacturer defined?

Comment: Hi Matt - Yes, that's precisely the issue.

Comment: Could you include the Traceback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you get the error is that your dictionary has a key `manufacturer`, but its value is `None`; so when you do `product.get('manufacturer', '')`, instead of getting the empty string - you get `None`, which of course has no encode method.

However, the real problem that your `str()` call is encapsulating the `encode` call, if you were just call `str()` on `None`, you wouldn't have this problem, because `str(None)` is `'None'`

Before:

```
row.append(str(product.get('manufacturer',"").encode('utf-8')))    
-------------------------------------------------------------^
```

After:

```
row.append(str(product.get('manufacturer',"")).encode('utf-8'))
---------------------------------------------^
```

You can also get rid of some of your repetitive code:

```
field_order = ['sku',
               'name',
               'description',
               'image',
               'manufacturer','upc','department','class','subclass']

row = [str(product.get(k)).encode('utf-8') for k in field_order]
csv.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

what u can do to avoid such error is first set the value in a variable then check if it is not none then u can continue , encoding will hit error when there is no value out of the get.

```
    x = .. 
    if x is not None : 
        # do the append and encode
```